# Android Intent Service APP silently work in background still start with white screen

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, intentservice

I write some background job with `IntentService` in Android Stuido. APP doing job well but still some layout issue. I read many examples for creating app without UI and tried them but no success.

When i start my app some white screen coming to screen and disappear quickly and `Toast` message where defined in `IntentService`. Just i need doing its job without any UI interactions and silently in background and terminate itself when service job done.

I know sounds like a virus :) Just i write some image processing thing for my Gallery. Is it possible?

I work on this about two days but no way. Let me share my codes;

**MainActivity;**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class);
        startService(intent);
        finish();

    }

}
```

**MyService;**

```
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Core.MinMaxLocResult;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class MyService extends IntentService {

    public MyService() {
        super("MyService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent workIntent) {

       Handler mHandler = new Handler(getMainLooper());
       mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Mission Complete!!!", 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml;**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.lacrymae.sampleapp">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".MyService" />
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front.autofocus" android:required="false"/>


</manifest>
```

Comment: you didn't add any layout that's why the white screen is showing. And Service is finished after it's finished it's work

Comment: So i don't want any UI coming to screen. Just want execute Service jobs without any UI. That's why did not add any layout. Isn't it ?

Comment: yeah, you are right.

Comment: That's the issue. Why still white screen coming and disappear quickly? I know Android is coldstart. Maybe that's why. But i wonder is there any way start the app without any UI.